# Using 8.5.3p4 in the Standard, how do I establish that T is reference-compatible to a T&?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, language-lawyer

Given

```
T w;
T& t = w;
```

how do I establish, using 8.5.3p4 and p5, that `r` binds to `t` below, i.e., that `T` is reference-compatible with `T&`?

```
T& r = t;
```

Observe that `T` is not the same type as `T&`, neither a base class of `T&`, and so according to 8.5.3p4 we can't say that `T` is reference-related to `T&`.

Comment: How would `r` bind to `t`? To me, both `t` and `r` bind to `w`, don't they? I mean, after `t` is defined, it's nothing but an alias for `w`, or am I wrong?

Comment: `T w; T& t = w; T& r = t;` is legal.

Comment: Yes, and equivalent to `T w; T& t = w; T& r = w;` ... no?

Comment: Of course -----------

Comment: Are you just asking for someone to demonstrate this equivalence by only using wording from the Standard?

Comment: It seems to me 8.5.3p4 is wrong or I'm missing something, and I don't know exactly what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initializer in the expression `T& r = t;" has type T, not T&, by 5/5 in the Standard as follows:

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” (8.3.2,
>   8.5.3), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference,
>   and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the
>   expression.

Answer (score 2):

**Short story:**

`T&` is *not* reference-compatible with `T`, however that is not relevant.

`T` is reference-compatible with `T` (itself).  That fact is used to apply 8.5.3p5.  Note the first few words of 8.5.3p5 *"A reference **to** type cv1 T1..."*.  So `cv1 T1 is T`, not `cv1 T1 is T&`.

**Long story:**

```
T& r = t;
```

`t` is an expression of type `T` (references are striped from expressions.  The type of the expression `t` is not `lvalue-reference to T` despite the fact that the type of the variable it names is) with a value category `lvalue`.

`T&r = t;` is a declaration that declares and initializes a variable `r` of type `lvalue-reference to T`, copy-initialized with the previously mentioned expression.

The action of this initialization is a direct reference binding.

In this case `T` is both reference-related and reference-compatible with itself as it is the *same type* with the *same cv qualification*.

8.5.3p4 just defines these two type relationships.

Now, look again at 8.5.3p5 rewritten to your specific example:

> A **reference to type “T”** is initialized by an **expression of type “T”**:
>
> - If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
> - - is an **lvalue**, and **“T” is reference-compatible with “T”**

So the `T` here is the value type, not that reference type.